# Tracking down EXC_BAD_ACCESS without NSZombie?

Tags: iphone, debugging, crash, exc-bad-access, nszombie

I've spent two days on this and I still can't find the cause of the crash.

I know it has something to do with trying to access an object that has been freed but I don't know which access or which object.

Whenever I google trying to find the source of EXC_BAD_ACCESS people suggest using NSZombies.  The problem is when I enable zombies (either in xcode via environment variable or in instruments via ObjectAlloc properties) the program doesn't crash where it usually does and the zombies don't report anything (nothing shows up in logs and nothing is flagged in instruments).  Is there something I'm missing with NSZombie?

I've tried utilizing some information from xcode's debugger and from ObjectAlloc in instruments but all the information is very cryptic and doesn't really help me.

I've set the debugger to stop on objective-c exceptions.  When it does it this is the call stack shown:

```
0 objc_msgSend
1 ??
2 -[UITableViewCell removeFromSuperView]
3 -[UIView dealloc]
... etc ...
```

First of all, what's the deal with '1 ??' ?  What do the question marks mean?  Second of all how can I know where this was called in my code?  All the operations stated are too generic (eg UIView dealloc, but which UIView? And where?).

Also when the exception occurs it points to assembly code which again, doesn't do me any good unless I was to spend hours trying to figure out what the code does.  I know some assembly but there *has* to be a better way... right?

Is there any way I can get meaningful information as to what was the last line that ran in my code before the exception occurred?

I've tried sprinkling some NSLogs and breakpoints around but it doesn't help me much because the crash happens *after* I pop a view controller from a navigation controller.  Everywhere I place breakpoints the breakpoints are reached fine (I can't find a point to break *after* the crash).  It's only when I 'continue' in the debugger that the exception occurs.  It's as if the crash happens outside of my code so I have no idea where to get a handle on it.

I've looked through my code and double checked that I adhere to all the memory management rules (at least to the best of my knowledge).  I'm sure it's something very subtle but I can't seem to find it.

If anyone has any ideas how to find such bugs without NSZombie please share.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running in debug mode? It should stop right away when the error occurs, and the stack trace will guide you to the line of code and the object that's causing the error.

Comment: What do you mean by 'debug mode'?  If you mean 'build&debug' in xcode and using the debugger and active configuration=debug then yes I did try that, as stated in my question.  The problem is the stack trace was too vague (see sample posted in my question).  It didn't help me find where in my code the problem was.  If you're talking about some other debug mode that I don't know of then please elaborate.  I'm fairly new to xcode (~ 1 month) so there might be features I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the problem.  I had a custom table cell class in which I called [super dealloc] first in the dealloc method (rather than last).  I guess I wrote this class in a hurry and didn't really think about it.  I'm guessing something got released in the parent that the child needed for releasing?

So I don't have a real answer to my own question but basically I found the problem using a combination of ad-hoc code tracing and various debugging techniques (breakpoints, NSLogs, trying to decypher cryptic stack trace,etc).

Actually the main strategy that helped me was commenting out code bit by bit until I stripped down the problem area into as simple as it gets while still keeping the crash intact.  This let me realize the problem wasn't where I thought it would be but in a more subtle area (eg in the dealloc method of a secondary class in this case).

I hope this can sort of help someone out.  I'll leave this question unanswered for a bit incase someone has a more thorough debugging strategy without relying on NSZombies.  Also if someone can clarify what those two question marks mean in the stack trace that would be helpful.

Comment: Once you call "super dealloc", the object itself has been deallocated, so any subsequent use of it (for example, by accessing an instance variable) is invalid and might cause a crash.